# Obvious but calm and cool riddle

Tags: riddle

<sub>They live in the eminence, the mountains high

Createth the doctrines, and abides by. 

O Potentates, O Overlords, t'is not a wry. 

Incarcerate, excutes - nefarious they sly.</sub>

---

`The first.`

> *The amnesiac phantom is already dead 
>
>   Gods of birds, maker of dread ! 
>
>   Brother of conspicuous, impish he shed.*

`The second`.

> *The titan Eldrazi, is dread as a whole 
>
>   Egyptians sun deity too, not very ole. 
>
>   Sounds frosty in the end, uplifter of soul.*

`The third.`

> *Placidly peaceful, pleasant person. 
>
>   'en Pomegranate periwenkle plum pigmentation 
>
>   Precipitation, pouring. (Not a pun !)*

---

Who are they ?

Comment: Is it a trivial riddle?

Comment: +1 Great work!  I think you can make the first quatrain scan slightly better by changing "abides" to "abideth".

Answer (score 13):

The answer is

> the Puzzling.SE [moderators](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators): Deusovi, Emrakul, and GentlePurpleRain (in that order).

*They live in the eminence, the mountains high*
*Createth the doctrines, and abides by.*
*O Potentates, O Overlords, t'is not a wry.*
*Incarcerate, excutes - nefarious they sly.*

> They can be seen as being set 'above' regular users, although they don't actually create the site 'doctrines' or policies, but only enforce them.

*The amnesiac phantom is already dead*
*Gods of birds, maker of dread !*
*Brother of conspicuous, impish he shed.*

> This is DEUSOVI: he doesn't sleep much, and we sometimes joke about him having a sock ("brother") called Obusovi. "Impish" ~ devious - an anagram of his username.

*The titan Eldrazi, is dread as a whole*
*Egyptians sun deity too, not very ole.*
*Sounds frosty in the end, uplifter of soul.*

> [Apparently](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Emrakul) EMRAKUL is "the largest and most fearsome of the Eldrazi". The Egyptian sun god is RA, and the final line refers to KUL or "cool".

*Placidly peaceful, pleasant person.*
*'en Pomegranate periwenkle plum pigmentation*
*Precipitation, pouring. (Not a pun !)*

> GENTLEPURPLERAIN's [profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain) is full of P-alliteration. Also, the first line means "gentle", the second "purple", and the third "rain" (thanks @F1Krazy).

Comment: I'd also like to note for the third one: "Placidly peaceful" = Gentle, "Pomegranate periwinkle plum pigmentation" = Purple, "Precipitation, pouring" = Rain

Comment: "Deus ovi" resembles the Latin for "God of Birds" (I don't know if the grammar is correct, but at least the roots of the words are).

Comment: I think it would have to be sheep or eggs rather than birds. (More precisely, I think "god of an egg" works; "god of eggs" and "god of sheep" don't quite.)